# What is the CSR for the S mode that is effective even in HS mode?

Tags: riscv, hypervisor

I'm new to RISC-V and have recently started learning about it. I'm currently developing with the help of documents available on riscv.org.

While investigating Hypervisor extensions, I noticed that there is no CSR (Control and Status Register) within the Hypervisor extension specifically for setting the trap vector. There used to be a CSR called htvec, but it seems to have been omitted in the current specifications.

I tried to find out how the trap vector used during HS mode is set, and I came across information that refers to stvec.

However, I couldn't find such information in the riscv-privileged.pdf ver.20211203 document. I believe there are other CSRs in S mode that become effective during HS mode, but I'm unsure where the specifications for such behavior are documented. Does anyone have this information?

I'm planning to post this question on Stack Overflow, so please feel free to adjust the wording accordingly.

Thank you.

Comment: Hypervisor extension extends the S mode and adds support to S mode to be able to run a hypervisor. So HS mode is basically S mode. So we don't have separate htvec. We will use S mode stvec csr. So think of it like this. Without a hypervisor we will have M mode firmware, OS in Smode and Apps in U mode. In this setup OS will use stvec csr for trap handler. Now lets take hypervisor setup, in which we have M mode firmware, Hypervisor in HS mode (S mode but H extended) and OS runs in VS mode and Apps in VU. Hypervisor will use stvec of HS mode(Smode) and OS will use vstvec. vstvec is add by H ext.

Comment: Read this for more information on this. https://drac.bsc.es/en/upc2